# Image not scaling correctly for each device screen

Tags: codenameone

I am having problems with multi image in the new GUI builder. It doesn't scale as should with individual skin or device screen. Is there another way to add multi image to scale according to screen size in the code?

I got this done very well in the old GUI builder. This is preventing me from having my app update.

Comment: Multi Image isn't a part of the GUI builder and it completely seamless to the design tool. It's a separate thing from the old and new GUI builder.

Comment: Please Shai, whenever I add image using multi Image in the theme and then add it in the new GUI as button or label icon, it uses the low resolution in any device you test it. This is what I mean by not scaling properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the designer and verify that the image is indeed a multi-image and that resolutions exist for all the right DPI's.

Look at the code and verify that the image is fetched using `getImage(String)` and isn't manipulated in any way.

Verify that you are using `Label` and not `ScaleImageLabel` or some similar class.

The [Phoenix demo](https://www.codenameone.com/demos-Phoenix.html) was created using the new GUI builder and uses a lot of multi-images.